# Value of this definite integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ \ln(x)}{x^2+2x+4} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I came across this question on brilliant.org and didn't know how to go about it:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ \ln(x)}{x^2+2x+4} dx $$

I tried to complete the squares in the denominator and then use a trigonometric substitution (with tan) but I didn't get anything beyond that.

How do I do it? Do we need to differentiate under the integral sign here?

Comment: Try to consider a suitable integral over the keyhole contour with the usual principle branch of the logarithm.

Comment: @FH93 Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I do not know complex analysis. If you know a method in real variables, please share it!

Comment: Break it up into $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, using $t=\dfrac1x$ for one of them, and see what happens.

Comment: I am quite certain that generally these kind of problems with real variables cannot be done. As mentioned, you need complex variables. While there are plenty of examples on the internet, if you are not familiar with this kind of integration, you need to take a course of complex analysis (which by the way is a great class!)

Comment: @Lucian When I try that, I am getting a denominator of $4t^2+2t+1$ because of that differential. In the numerator you get of course that ln term back. I am a little puzzled how this would help. Would you mind give some hints here?

Comment: Might be better with $(0,2)$ and $(2,\infty)$ and $t = 4/x$

Comment: @RobertIsrael I am still getting $4t^2+2t+1$ in the denominator. How does that work out?

Comment: I happened to be able to sp

Comment: You can try following Robert Israel's suggestion.

Comment: With $x = 4/t$,
$$ \dfrac{dx}{x^2 + 2x + 4} = \dfrac{-4 dt/t^2}{16/t^2 + 8/t + 4} = \dfrac{-dt}{4 + 2t + t^2}$$

Answer (score 16):

This CAN be done with real variables and no, you do not need to differentiate with respect to a parameter. Here's how:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+2x+4} dx $$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{{(x+1)}^2+3}dx $$
$$I=\frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{ ({ \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3}} })^2 + 1} dx $$
Now, set 
$$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3}} = \tan(t)$$
Thus $t$ is between $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
We now have
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln{ (\sqrt{3} \tan(t) - 1 )} dt $$
Now, use this property:
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) dx$$
So, we have:
$$I= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln{ \left( \sqrt{3} \frac{ \sqrt{3} + \tan(t) }{\sqrt{3} \tan(t) - 1} - 1\right) }dt $$
On simplifying,
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln{\left( \frac{4}{\sqrt{3} \tan(t) - 1}\right)} dt $$
Thus,
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln{(4)} dt - I$$
$$I= \frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt{3} } \ln{2} $$
and we are done.

Comment: Definitely (+1) and so the question that pops in my mind is: Will this approach work for any non factorable quadratic (negative discriminant) with one $lnx$ in the numerator? That tan sub may give some trouble I suspect?

Comment: @imranfat Yep, I'm guessing it will. Complex analysis/ diff under the integral sign to the rescue then!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, use a keyhole contour in the complex plane, which we'll call $C$.  Here though you should consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C dx \frac{\log^2{z}}{z^2+2 z+4} $$

I will leave it to the reader to show that the integral vanishes over the circular portions of $C$; we are thus left with the contour integral equaling

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^2{x}-(\log{x}+i 2 \pi)^2}{x^2+2 x+4} = -i 4 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx\frac{\log{x}}{x^2+2 x+4} + 4 \pi^2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2+2 x+4}$$

Now, the integral on the right we need to know as well.  We may evaluate that any way we wish, but let's stick to this formalism.  This integral may be evaluated using the same contour and the residue theorem.  Let

$$R_n = \sum_k \operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k} \frac{\log^{n+1}{z}}{z^2+2 z+4}$$

for $n=0,1$.  That is,

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log^{n+1}{z}}{z^2+2 z+4} = i 2 \pi R_n$$

Then from the above, you may show that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx\frac{\log{x}}{x^2+2 x+4} = i \pi R_0 - \frac12 R_1$$

Note that the poles of the integrands are at $z_1=2 e^{i 2 \pi/3}$ and $z_2 = 2 e^{i 4 \pi/3}$.  Note that we must use these arguments because of how we defined the contour.

We mat deduce that

$$R_0 = \frac{\log{2}+i 2 \pi/3}{i 2 \sqrt{3}} + \frac{\log{2}+i 4 \pi/3}{-i 2 \sqrt{3}} = -\frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

$$R_1 = \frac{(\log{2}+i 2 \pi/3)^2}{i 2 \sqrt{3}} + \frac{(\log{2}+i 4 \pi/3)^2}{-i 2 \sqrt{3}} = -\frac{2 \pi \log{2}}{3 \sqrt{3}} - i \frac{2 \pi^2}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Putting it all together, the imaginary pieces cancel and we get

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx\frac{\log{x}}{x^2+2 x+4} = \frac{\pi \log{2}}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+2x+4} dx\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $x=2t$,

\begin{align}I&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left(2t\right)}{t^2+t+1}\,dt\\ 
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln t}{t^2+t+1}\,dt+\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2+t+1}\,dt
\end{align}

The first integral is $0$ (perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{t}$)

\begin{align}I&=\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2+t+1}\,dt\\
&=\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}\,dt\\
&=\frac{2\ln 2}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}\,dt\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $u=\dfrac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}$

\begin{align}I&=\frac{2\ln 2}{3}\times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+u^2}\,du\\
&=\frac{\ln 2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\arctan(\infty)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{\ln 2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi\ln 2}{3\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks to notice the typo. Fixed